# Accessing the AWS gateway resource in another stack in cdk stack

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, api-gateway

I have a stack where an api gateway resource is created. I have a construct under this stack from where i need to create a method to the above resource. I tried passing the resource as the props to the construct. But it throws error as

> throw new Error(`${construct.constructor?.name ?? 'Construct'} at '${Node.of(construct).path}' should be created in the scope of a Stack, but no Stack found`);

Any idea on creating and passing the aws api gateway resource inside a stack and pass it to the construct or another stack.

Comment: Passing it as a prop works. The issue is with your code, you can add it to the question.

Comment: Found the issue, the above is due to the scope. I was not passing the current object instead i was sending the global scope. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the scope that is used to create the construct. Changed the scope of the construct to `this` then it worked fine.